# How to remove a little code redundancy

Tags: php

Basically I have a code:

```
 $response = myFunction();
```

I need to repeat this call if there was an error like this:

```
do {
   $response = myFunction();

} while ( isset($response['error']) );
```

But I want to `usleep(500);` too if there was an error. I could do like this, but I don't find it so elegant:

```
do {
   $response = myFunction();

   if (isset($response['error']))
     usleep(500);

} while ( isset($response['error']) );
```

What Can i do? Maybe something like this (not very elegant neither)

```
while( isset($response['error']) && !usleep(500) );
```

### Edit

There is another possibility... With the use of `goto`. But I am always reluctant to `goto` codes

```
retry:
$response = myFunction();
if (isset($response['error'])) {
  usleep(500);
  goto retry;
}
```

To me this seems the most clear and redundancy-free solution.   What do you think?

Comment: Actually you can't do "!usleep(500)" as usleep() doesn't return anything. It doesn't seem like there's anything wrong or unelegant about your code if this is what you need it to do.  I am curious as to why the usleep() in the first place?

Comment: I honestly think your first version (with the extra "if") is perfectly clear. It's a matter of coincidence that your condition is `isset($response['error'])` instead of a simple variable, but still perfectly readable. You could add a comment above the "if" to state that you sleep in order to attempt a subsequent request.

Comment: I don't think that `elegant` is a useful tag :)

Comment: I think formal code would use a explicit flag: `$retry = true; do { ... ; if (isset(...)) { usleep(500); } else { $retry = false; } } while ($retry);` but nonetheless..

Comment: @AymanSafadi: exactly because usleep returns void I must do a `!usleep `call in the do-while

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
while (true) {
    $response = myFunction();

    if (isset($response['error'])) {
        usleep(500);
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Having said that, trying to hammer a function until it returns the correct result may be a sign of a badly thought-out architecture and there may be a better solution for the whole problem to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Suggested solution to remove the redundancy where you check for isset twice. This is a bit cleaner.

```
do {
    $response = myFunction();
    if( $error = isset($response['error']) )
        usleep(500);
} while( $error );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define a function like this :

```
function isset_wait($var)
{
    if(isset($var))
    {
        usleep(500);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

then your code will be muche easrier to read :

```
do {
    $response = myFunction();
} while ( isset_wait($response['error']) );
```

Comment: Assuming that `$response` does not contain the key `error` when there is no error, this will throw `E_NOTICE`s.